# dynamically change ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have the following select input

```
<select
    ng-model="people"
    ng-options="capacity for capacity in Range(1, roomCapacity)"
    class="form-control"
    id="howmany"
    ng-required="noOfPeopleRequired()">
</select>
```

range is

```
$scope.Range = function(start, end) {
    var result = [];
    if (end === 1) {
        result.push(1);
    } else {
        for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            result.push(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

I am watching an int and when that changes setting the value of roomCapacity to it but unfortunately the range of options does not change in my select

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fo array data source, you could use the expression below:

> **select as label for value in array**

Try this:

**JS**

```
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.Range = function(start,end){
        var result = [];
        if(end===1){
            result.push(1);
        }else{
            for(var i=start;i<=end;i++){
                result.push(i);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" id="roomCapacity" ng-model="roomCapacity"/>
  <select
    ng-model="people" ng-options="capacity as capacity for capacity in Range(1,roomCapacity)"
  >
    <option value="">Please select</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LfEMw/1/)